# Error - The container 'Maven Dependencies' references non existing library

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, jitpack

I'm doing an assignment that makes use of jitpack and maven but I'm struggling to get jitpack to work at all. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong so any advice would be greatly helpful.

So the error I'm getting is;

```
Missing artifact com.github.PeadarC:Repository2:jar:5560d83
```

Here's my pom.xml file;

```js
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>partB</groupId>
  <artifactId>partB</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jitpack.io</id>
            <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.PeadarC</groupId>
            <artifactId>Repository2</artifactId>
            <version>5560d83</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

[jitpack.io's main page](https://jitpack.io) has a "maven" tab that tells you what to put in your POM.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The thing is that I have exactly that in my pom so I really can't figure out why it won't work

Comment: What I see on that page and what I see above are not the same thing.

Comment: Well the first part is my maven code for the pom and the <dependencies> tag is needed to avoid a different error. The <version> tag is either 1,1.0.0 or the code that I have used, to specify which release it is. Putting in exactly what is on that page causes another litany of issues